# Make target/dependency that is not a file

Tags: hadoop, makefile, dependencies, hbase

I have a processing job that has a lot of intermediate 'things' that all depend on each other and ultimately create some kind of output.

In the past I've often used gmake for such a task.

The problem is that this time some of those 'things' are not files/directories on the local file system. In fact they are files on the hadoop file system and tables in hbase/mysql.

So far I've not been able to find a way to let gmake have a dependency or a target that is something special (like an hadoop file, database table, etc.).

The only thing I've come up with is to have a scripting that 'mirrors' the state in hadoop/database/... towards (empty)files on the local disk. And the let gmake look at those files.

What is a preferred solution for this kind of task?

- Use the mirror trick.
- Use gmake in a slightly different way?
- Use a different tool that does support this?
- ...

Comment: GNU make cannot operate on anything other than files, using standard system file operations like fopen(), etc.  If you want to use make you'll have to construct a local set of files that mirrors the state of the remote files, as you've tried already.

Comment: Does an alternative exist that does support this kind of 'remote dependencies'? Perhaps via custom plugins?

Comment: Nothing possible for GNU make.  I don't know about other build tools.